# thrift setup issue

Tags: thrift

I have VS 2010 and have downloaded the required tar & zip files from Apache web.  There are basically two VC++ Projects in the thrift folder.  One is at `thrift-0.8.0\thrift-0.8.0\lib\cpp\thrift.sln`  and another one is at `thrift-0.8.0\thrift-0.8.0\compiler\cpp\compiler.sln`, so basically two projects.
I have compiled successfully the `thrift.sln` project and am able to generate successfully the two lib files `libthrift.lib` and `libthriftnb.lib`. Now after this I have couple of questions.

a) How do I generate this `thrift.exe` now?
b) I tried compiling `compiler.sln` project but am getting the error below:

```
Build started: Project: compiler, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
flex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
bison' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The command "flex -o "src/thriftl.cc" src/thriftl.ll
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: bison -y -o "src/thrifty.cc" --defines="src/thrifty.h" src/thrifty.yy
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 9009."
```

c) How do I compile the thrift file now?

For testing purposes, I directly downloaded the thrift exe from the Apache website and have created a sample thrift program but I'm getting an error:

```
[ERROR:E:/thrift-0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0/lib/cpp/Debug/calculator.thrift:3] (last to
en was '02')
syntax error
[FAILURE:E:/thrift-0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0/lib/cpp/Debug/calculator.thrift:3] Parser
error during include pass.
```

Please suggest
Thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 0):

Thrift Exe which is provided on Apache Web is Win32 Compiled Exe, So you can directly use to create autogenerated code from your Thrift file, With required flag for language
Thrift -c java tezt.thrift, & then can use in for IPC.

Answer (score 0):

As of thrift version 0.10.0

The thrift compiler project is `compiler\cpp\compiler.vcproj`. It has dependencies on Flex and Bison (WinFlexBison for Windows) which is what the error is indicating.

Alternatively, you can use the CMake files to generate visual studio solutions.

See [Apache Thrift on Windows](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/apache-thrift-on-windows/) for detailed instructions.